# Laravel 5.6 - Validate Numbers and spaces

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5.6 I am validating alphabetic characters and spaces only in regex like this..

```
'name' => 'required|regex:/^[\pL\s\-]+$/u',
```

This works as far as I can see, I am now trying to validate numbers only and spaces like this..

```
'telephone' => 'required|regex:/[0-9 ]+/',
```

But this is not working and allows me to enter 'f4' where it should fail.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try `'regex:/(^[0-9 ]+$)+/'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`[0-9 ]+`](https://regex101.com/r/pCDPMF/2) will match `4` in `f4`

Try using anchors to assert the start and the end of the line `^` and `$`

[`^[0-9 ]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/pCDPMF/3)

Note that this will also match whitespaces only because the [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) matches digit or a whitespace one or more times..